# How to show error on duplicates in array, only in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

```js
type MyType = ('t' | 'd' | 's')[]

// This will work without problem
const value: MyType = ['t', 'd']

// I expect an error from this code, because it has duplicates in it
const value: MyType = ['t', 't']
```

I would like to find custom type, where I expect to see an error for duplicates

Comment: You could list all allowed combinations: `type My type = ['t', 'd'] | ['t', 's'] | ...`